# ArcMap does not "remember" linked custom .style files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, style, style-manager, customize-mode

I have a two sets of custom .style files that I would like to have ArcMap load every time I open the program. (Ex: the thematic color ramps from Color Brewer.) It's a small thing but I don't want to have to manually add them every time.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

It is under Customize > Style Manager > Styles..., and then I just needed to click "Set as Default List."

To read more about this see [Referencing styles in a map document](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/styles-and-symbols/referencing-styles-in-a-map-document.htm) in the ArcMap Online Help.